# How do you turn a list of (x,y) coordinate points into a list of integers in the same format?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

[This is the input and output I am looking for given the user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KriKs.png)

I want to do this using a function. I am assuming you will have to iterate through each set of points to convert them to integers, then back to a list?

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: You can extract all set of coordinates from the string using a regex (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and findall, then treat each set to convert it to the desired format.

Comment: Now do a little research, and try to post at least some starting code.

Comment: The input **is not** "a list of (x,y) coordinate points". It is... just a string.

Comment: Let's call it a string of x,y coordinates, without the () :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

```
import re

a = '3,4 5,6 7,8 12,8 3,456'
```

Now you could use:

```
raw_coords = re.findall(r'[0-9]+,[0-9]+', a)
```

But then you'd have to use more regex to extract x and y from each "x,y" string

A more straightforward way would be to separately extract the x values and y values from your initial list: look up "lookbehind assertions" and "lookahead assertions".

For example:

```
xlist = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?=,)', a)
```

(explanation: this finds all maximal strings of digits that are placed just before a ',')

For now, I'll let you do some research and try to complete the process.